# Access denied but why?

Tags: bug

The significant part of the browser message:

```
While trying to retrieve the URL: http://serverfault.com/questions/388858/how-to-fix-file-name-too-long-error-in-apache2

The following error was encountered:

Access Denied.
```

I've had this a few times over the last few months or so. Clearly not all is well in SF world.

If this is happening because the question being edited, moved or closed then I'd expect to see a more intelligent and user friendly message.

Comment: [status-worksforme] -- Have you perhaps been saying unkind things about the server when you thought it couldn't hear you? :)

Comment: Looks like a... server fault. (ha ha)

Comment: Strange, you're seeing a `403` from a main Question/Show page?  We're not seeing anything like that in the logs for your account in the last week.  If you see it again, would you take a screenshot, please?  It could be our load balancer config is having issues.

Comment: @Jarrod, a screen shot is only going to show the same error message, so I really don't see how that will help. The error occurred when I clicked on the question from the front page. Clicking on other questions worked perfectly. The only other relevant information I can supply the next time this happens is the exact date and time.

Comment: @vortaq7, I don't recall ever saying unkind things about the server. Unlike people, I treat servers with due respect.